# Lisk blockchain: what is the maximum block size that makes sense?

Tags: blockchain

I'm new to Lisk blockchain technology and I am looking for some technical guidance of how the details of it looks like.

What is the preferred Lisk blockchain block size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lisk SDK has a maximum block size of 30kb.
The value is currently configurable between 10kb and 30kb.

Lisk HQ tested up to 100kb with success, so it's possible that later version will push those config boundaries.

You can always edit the config schema ( framework/src/schema/application_config_schema.ts ) in the SDK sources code to edit those values yourself ; but you must take into account the impact it has on the network : you may need to increase the block time, and set it to 15s instead of 10s for example.